# I can't seem to install numpy

Tags: python, numpy, import

I tried to install numpy, but whenever I start my program, I get these messages.

```
Error importing numpy: you should not try to import numpy from
    its source directory; please exit the numpy source tree, and relaunch
    your python interpreter from there.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python34\numpy\__init__.py", line 155, in <module>
from numpy.__config__ import show as show_config
ImportError: No module named 'numpy.__config__'
```

I don't understand what it means by not importing numpy from it's source directory. Where am I supposed to import it from instead?

Comment: You did not install numpy correctly, you took the sources or something and unzipped them to the Python 3.4 folder, that is not how to install numpy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error means just what it says. You are probably in `C:\Python34` or `C:\Python34\numpy` when you run `python` on the command line. Switch to another directory (such as `C:\`) and run `python`, then try `import numpy` and see what happens.

From your comments, it looks like you didn't properly install `numpy`, just unzipped it into your `C:\Python34` directory. The easiest way to install this modules is to visit [Christoph Gohlke's Python Extension Packages for Windows Repository](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) and go down to [`numpy`](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy). Download the `cp34` file for your version of Python (either 32- or 64-bit). Then, on the command line, switch to your Downloads directory and run, for example

```
pip install numpy‑1.9.2+mkl‑cp34‑none‑win_amd64.whl
```

(if you downloaded the 64-bit version) and it should install quite nicely. If you get a `Command not found` error for `pip`, make sure you add `C:\Python34\Scripts` to your PATH environment variable. Once you do that, restart the command line and it should work perfectly.

Gohlke has a ton of pre-compiled modules for Python, mostly relating to scientific computing, and I always check there first before installing from [PyPI](https://pypi.python.org) with `pip`.

Comment: Sorry, but what do you mean by switch to another directory? I'm not running python on the command line, I'm running it from the IDLE.

Comment: In IDLE, please run `import os; print(os.getcwd())` and let me know what the result is.

Comment: C:\Users\User\Dropbox\School Work\Computing

Comment: @Yoast regardless of the above, try this: exit IDLE, then in Windows Explorer move the `C:\Python34\numpy` directory to some other folder, like `C:\Users\Yoast` (or whatever your username is). Then, restart IDLE and try to import numpy again.

Comment: All I get is: ImportError: No module named 'numpy' @Matt

Comment: @Yoast please see the edit to my answer above. This should solve your problems.

Comment: @Yoast no problem at all, glad to help