# Numpy for windows installing problems

Tags: python, numpy, environment-variables

I have been trying to install Numpy for python 3.4, and it keeps going wrong, I tried following the advice at [I can't seem to install numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28919754/i-cant-seem-to-install-numpy), but I keep getting told that pip is not a recognised command, even after I add ;C:\Python34\Scripts; to my PATH variable, anyone know why this might be happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this problem as well running Windows 8. I found a helpful solution from a word doc from Worcester Polytechnic Institute. Here is the PDF (http://web.cs.wpi.edu/~cs1004/c15/Resources/Windows/SettingUpPython_Windows.pdf).

They provide an installer for it at (http://www.cs.wpi.edu/~cs1004/c15/Resources/Windows/python-3.4.2.amd64.msi)

Should be an easy solution.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the links for reference.

Comment: Thanks NightShadeQueen, will do - for me the best solution was just downloading their installer (link # 2), which, according to their description, is able to detect and download the appropriate version of NumPy needed for your PC (ie. 32-bit v. 64-bit systems).